# How to translate a require into an import statement in es6

Tags: javascript, import, require

I am trying to get this to work in firebase:

```
var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator("<YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET>");
var token = tokenGenerator.createToken({ uid: "1", some: "arbitrary", data: "here" });
```

However I get a `require is not defined error`

I then switch to this:

```
import FirebaseTokenGenerator from("firebase-token-generator");
  var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator("<YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET>");
  var token = tokenGenerator.createToken({ uid: "uniqueId1", some: "arbitrary", data: "here" });
```

and I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

why is this failing and have I got the import right?

Comment: The from in Import from is just a string. No "parens".

Comment: Are you using a transpiler? [Doesn't look like it's natively supported yet.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility)